# Triggers in SQL Server - what are they?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, triggers

I have used SQL Server 2005. But I have not used triggers, please somebody help me to let me know what is trigger?

Types of trigger, how to use that in SQL Server 2005?

What are advantages and disadvantages to use triggers?

Thanks in advance

Comment: exists a lot of resource that explain you what is trigger. Follow one http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/07/24/sql-server-2005-server-and-database-level-ddl-triggers-examples-and-explanation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trigger is a procedure that automatically executes when something happens in a database.

from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger):

> A database trigger is procedural code that is automatically executed
>   in response to certain events on a particular table or view in a
>   database. The trigger is mostly used for maintaining the integrity of
>   the information on the database. For example, when a new record
>   (representing a new worker) is added to the employees table, new
>   records should be created also in the tables of the taxes, vacations
>   and salaries

There is a lot of information about them online:

[MSDN - CREATE TRIGGER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

[An Introduction to Triggers](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/an-introduction-to-triggers-part-i)

[Exploring SQL Server Triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164047.aspx)

Comment: There are lot of simillar questions about the Trigger, @Neeru Rana should try by himself to find the one related to him